# Footer in every page in TPPDF ios

Tags: ios, swift, tppdf

I am able to add the footer in a pdf, using TPPDF library in iOS. But I am not able to keep the footer on every page of the PDF. Any solution for the same?

Here is how I have used the footer:

**let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Page 1 of 1", attributes: regularTextAttributes)

document?.add(.footerLeft, attributedText: attributedString)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a single `PDFDocument` instance, or you have different ones for every page you have in the final generate document?
From what I've seen when you add a footer it's the same for the whole document (`PDFDocument` instance) and than you generate the final document via the `PDFGenerator`, but if you are using an array of documents (many `PDFDocuments`) and generate the final document via `PDFMultiDocumentGenerator`, then you'll need to add your footer to every single `PDFDocument`

note: if you are using the `PDFMultiDocumentGenerator` you might have issues with the default pagination of the document, and will need to manually handle the pagination's "page" and "total" with the `customClosure` `PDFPaginationStyle`